# Singleton object behaviour in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, singleton

Consider I want to create a singleton object for each user accessing a particular feature in the website. This object is not a Model.

```py
class NavApi:
    __instance = None

    @staticmethod
    def get_instance():
        """ Static access method. """
        if NavApi.__instance is None:
            Client()
        return NavApi.__instance
```

In views file

```py
@csrf_exempt
def get_folder_tree(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        nav_api = NavAPI.get_instance()
        folders = nav_api.listing_folders(request.POST.get('id'))
        return render(request, "folder_tree.html", {'folders': folders, 'page1': False})


@csrf_exempt
def get_prev_folder_tree(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        nav_api = NavAPI.get_instance()
        page1,folders = nav_api.listing_prev_folder_tree()
        return render(request, "folder_tree.html", {'folders': folders,'page1':page1})
```

The reason for using Singleton is that the class object has few members which defines the state of the folder/contents/current folder_id etc. And it should not be created for every view. It needed to be reused

But when I tried to run it as public, using ngrok and shared the linked to my friend, and testing the navigation features,

We ended up using the same singleton object. When I was browsing contents of Folder A, and he was browsing contents of Folder B, we ended up recieving contents of the same folder(either A or B).
How to overcome this?

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand your question.
So you have a singleton, but what you really like to have is one singleton per user or do you in fact want one singleton per session (Meaning if the same user accesses fro two different browsers the same url, should it share the singleton or not)??

Comment: Almost same, 
So the output will be like he is suppose to browse through folders front and back, just like a finder in mac does, but this happens inside webpage, as I am using API to retrieve folder infos from the respective server.

So When he moves in and out of folders I need to track the folder details in terms of a object, which can be reused among other views.

Answer (score 2):

Python is not PHP... In a typical production setup, your app will be served by many long-running processes, so you can NOT expect to reliably use process memory as a way to persist global state (a singleton IS global state) from request to request - you can have the same user having two consecutive requests served by different processes and a same process serving requests for two different users.

If you want to maintain per-user state between requests, you have to use some shared storage, the very obvious solution here being sessions.

> Can I get any reference to a resource which deals a similar case?

Using sessions ? [That's fully documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/)

Oh and yes: if all you're doing is to navigate thru folders, you are badly misusing http verbs:

> The POST method is used to request that the origin server accept the entity enclosed in the request as a new subordinate of the resource identified by the Request-URI in the Request-Line.

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Here you are just reading resources, so you want to use GET requests.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the headsup. Can I get any reference to a resource which deals a similar case?